# Seeing a message from CUPS "Attempting to set page size to letter is not allowed" on active print job, while printing on network badge printer

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, css

I have a CSS/HTML page that I am trying to print to a network badge printer. It is 300 dpi. I send a PNG (1016 x 642 pixels) and it prints badges just fine. However, when I try to print this html/CSS on the same nothing seems to happen. I then open my browser and login to localhost:631 and see all active print jobs and then a message corresponding to failed job "Attempting to set page size to letter is not allowed". I am not sure if this is a CSS/HTML (I have a code @media print {.... } that would only print specified parts) issue or printer settings issue. Any guidance is appreciated.
OS:Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The issue was "Printing Properties" in Ubuntu for badge printer. By default it had selected "US Letter" as the default size instead of CR-80 or CR-79 option. Changing that to the appropriate type resolved the issue. For images though it appears to bypass this and scales the images.